# Is it possible to map claims by default on a service provider?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Is it possible to map claims by default on a service provider ? So that when I create one it already has some predefined mapping if for example I have several service provider and I don't want to do the mapping for all of them since it's the same or most of it is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Out of the box, it is not possible to have a **default claim mapping** for all the service providers.

Since you have many service providers with same claim mapping, if you use [service provider API's](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Using+the+Service+Provider+API#UsingtheServiceProviderAPI-createApplication) for the service provider creation then you can reduce the time for service provider claim configuration.